# Java Regex Explanation

Tags: java, regex

Can someone please explain the meaning of `\\A` and `\\z` to me? I am assuming that they have a special meaning in this regular expression because they are being escaped (but I could be wrong and they could just stand for A and z, respectively). Thanks!

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\A(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\z");
```

Comment: Check here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: You need the double backslashes, cause in Java a single backslash escapes the next character. So to achieve \A you need \\A. That is the way of Java :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\A` means "start of string", and `\z` means "end of string".

You might have seen `^` and `$` in this context, but their meaning can vary: If you compile a regex using `Pattern.MULTILINE`, then they change their meaning to "start of line" and "end of line". The meaning of `\A` and `\z` never changes.

There also exists `\Z` which means "end of string, before any trailing newlines", which is similar to what `$` does in multiline mode (where it matches right before the line-ending newline character, if it's there).

Comment: I was about to ask whether \A and \z are similar to ^ and $. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 4):

This Java expression:

```
Pattern.compile("\\A(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\z")
```

produces this regex:

```
\A(\d+)\.(\d+)\z
```

where `\A` means "start-of-string" and `\z` means "end-of-string".

So, that pattern matches any string consisting of one or more digits, plus a decimal point, plus one or more digits.

For details about all aspects of Java regex notation, see [the Javadoc for `java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

check out this reference

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

according to that `\A` matches the start of input, and `\z` matches the end of input.

the reason why they have `\\` before them instead of just 1 `\` is because the `\` is also being escaped.